# How to do addEventListener click or change for select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener, mutation-observers

I have select option, but not so simple...
Anything what i try with addEventListener doesn't work

I need to addEventListener('change') on changes of select, or i need addEventListener('click') on select option in dropdown list

```js
const material = document.querySelector('.calc_custom_select');
console.log(material)
material.addEventListener("change", () => {
        console.log('yeap')
})
```

```html
<select class="calc_custom_select selectized" placeholder="Choose" name="calc_slopes" data-price_per_item="625.86" data-quantity="1" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;"><option value="backlit" selected="selected">bakclit</option></select>
<option value="backlit" selected="selected">backlit</option>


<div class="selectize-control calc_custom_select single">
<div class="selectize-input items full has-options has-items">
<div class="item" data-value="banner">banner</div>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" style="width: 4px;"></div><div class="selectize-dropdown single calc_custom_select" style="display: none; width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 0px;"><div class="selectize-dropdown-content"></div></div></div>
```

Comment: the question you asked in the title is already answered by yourself in your code. Anyway the problem in your code is that you are not actually trying to do what you are saying because it looks like you are actually attempting to add a facade on top of the canonic dropdown. By the way, your select element has display:none and of course you cannot trigger the change event on an invisible control. Plus, instead of using querySelector over a class, you could just use a more straightforward approach to select one single element (by id for example).

Comment: if you remove the display:none style from the select and you add one more option to it, you will see that the change event gets fired and your handler will perform its logic as expected

Comment: @DiegoD if i do first addEventListener(click) for first option in select, and when call function where addEventListener(click or change) when display block it's does'nt work too(